# Is UNION faster than UNION ALL with DISTINCT?

Tags: sql-server, union

`UNION` can eliminate "Distinct" use to optimize the query? Like below, NO distinct is needed if the `UNION` is used to return distinct set.

#### Sample data

```
declare @T1 Table
(
ObjId1 int ,
Name varchar(100)
)

declare @T2 Table
(
ObjId1 int ,
Name varchar(100)
)

insert into @T1
select 1,'Name1'
UNION ALL 
select 1,'Name1'
UNION ALL
select 2,'Name2'

insert into @T2
select 1,'Name1'
UNION ALL 
select 1,'Name1'
UNION ALL
select 2,'Name2'
UNION ALL
select 3,'name3'
```

If two select lists are written as a `UNION`, this will return the distinct list of records. If we instead use `UNION ALL`, and put an explicit `DISTINCT` in the two selects, will that cost more?

#### Example

```
SELECT 'Table:T1', * 
FROM @T1

SELECT 'Table:T2', * 
FROM @T2

SELECT * 
FROM @T1
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM @T2

SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM @T1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM @T2
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but the cost should be same for union all + distinct and union

Comment: `UNION` is actually `UNION DISTINCT`, the keyword `DISTINCT` is optional.

Comment: UNION ALL is generally faster than just UNION since the UNION ALL doesn't need to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

It won't eliminate the cost - the price of making sure there are no duplicates must still be paid.

The same would apply for using `GROUP BY`.

You can test this by comparing the execution plans, which are likely to be similar across all the variations.